# WPF Binding Image Source

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, imagesource

maybe stupid question, but I don't know anymore...

I have ViewModel class like this:

```
public class MainWindowsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ImageSource _img;
    public ImageSource StatusImage
    {
        get { return _img; }
        set
        {
            _img = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Binding in XAML looks like this:

```
  <Window.DataContext>
    <VM:MainWindowsViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>
    <Image x:Name="gui_image_status" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="144,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="29" Source="{Binding Path=StatusImage}" />
```

And I set content of ImageSource like this:

```
MainWindowsViewModel _view = new MainWindowsViewModel();

        var yourImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(String.Format("Sources/{0}.png", "red"), UriKind.Relative));
        _view.StatusImage = yourImage;
```

But it does not work. I think that problem is in that `NotifyPropertyChanged`, because I tried place brake point in the `set` and `get`. `Get` triggered few times at the start, after then `set` triggered as well with correct ImageSource, but after then `get` did not triggered anymore. Like no setting ever happened.

It's really simply binding that I have done many times similarly...I don't know why it doesn't work this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating two instances of your MainWindowsViewModel class, one in XAML by

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <VM:MainWindowsViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

and one in code behind by

```
MainWindowsViewModel _view = new MainWindowsViewModel();
```

So your code behind sets the property on a different view model instance than the one the view is bound to.

Change your code behind to this:

```
var viewModel = (MainWindowsViewModel)DataContext;
viewModel.StatusImage = new BitmapImage(...);
```

Comment: I think that it's just an example but not real code. I hope.

Comment: You mean the question? That's certainly real code, and also a common mistake. I've seen this quite often here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Should work by something like `Application.Current.MainWindow.DataContext`, but better would be not to to create a view model instance in XAML and instead create a globally accessible instance in your code behind, i.e. in the App class.

Comment: Jeez, I'm dumb. But how can I obtain that instance of viewModel from another class? Like MainWindow.DataContex..or something.?

Comment: I don't know why I didn't do it as I always do. Like this: I have ViewModel defined in Window.Resources and in MainWindow.xaml.cs like this `MainWindowsViewModel = Resources["MainWindowsViewModel"] as MainWindowsViewModel;`
I think, it's best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any problems in your code, but you can try to check few things.

1. Check that your Image added to the project and set build action of images to Content (copy if newer).
2. Before updating ImageSource call Freeze method to prevent error: "Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject"

   ```
   var yourImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(String.Format("Sources/{0}.png", "red"), UriKind.Relative));
   yourImage.Freeze();
   _view.StatusImage = yourImage;
   ```

Also, there is an easier way to bind image in WPF. You can use string as a source and set a resource path to the binded property:

```
public string StatusImage  
{
    get { return "/AssemblyName;component/Sources/red.png"; }
}
```