# why does the datacontext in my WPF project function correctly from code behind but not from xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have been working on a small sample Wpf Mvvm project for experimenting with INotifyPropertyChanged interface.  The project actually works correctly, but the problem that I am having is that the project only works correctly if I set the DataContext in the code behind of MainWindow.xaml.  If I try to set the DataContext in the xaml markup then some of the features of the project don't work. The UI contains a textblock, textbox (for entering text to display in the textblock OnPropertyChanged) and submit button (which really does nothing except provide a place to lose focus from textbox) and 3 other buttons (color buttons) for changing the background color of the UI.  The default color of the UI is orange -- until the color is changed by clicking any of the color buttons

There are 3 viewModels, PersonViewModel (which the textbox binds to), BackgroundViewModel (for the color buttons) and a MainViewModel which combines the two other viewModels.  The viewModels reside in the viewModels folder of the project. There is also an ObservableObject class (ViewModelBase class basically) which implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface and gets inherited by PersonViewModel and BackgroundViewModel.  ObservableObject.cs resides in the root folder of the project.

The Project isn't pure Mvvm.  The color buttons use a click event in the code behind of MainWindow.xaml.  If I set the DataContext in the Code behind of MainWindow.xaml everything works correctly.  If I set the DataContext in the xaml markup -- the textbox/textblock features works but the color buttons won't change the background color of the UI.  When I step through the code it runs through all the code correctly but the UI background colors don't change.  I am guessing it is a binding thing.

The sample project can be downloaded  [here](http://www.codersonline.com/billybob/codingStuff/wpfstuff3/NotifyChangeExample.zip)

The code is below.  How can I make this project function correctly if I set the DataContext in the xaml markup?  I tried the following binding on the Grid which WILL set the default orange color for the UI, but the color buttons don't work:

```
<Grid Background="{Binding Background.Color}" DataContext="{StaticResource bc}">
```

--MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="NotifyChangeExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NotifyChangeExample"
    xmlns:VM="clr-namespace:NotifyChangeExample.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="550" Width="525">

    <!--<Window.DataContext>        
        <VM:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>-->

    <Window.Resources>
        <VM:MainViewModel x:Key="bc" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{Binding Background.Color}" DataContext="{StaticResource bc}">
    <!--<Grid Background="{Binding Background.Color}">-->
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="False" Margin="0,82,0,0">
            <StackPanel Width="150" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Person.Name, StringFormat=Welcome (0)}" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Person.Name, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <Button>Submit</Button>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" >
                <Button Click="Red_Clicked">Red Background</Button>
                <Button Click="Blue_Clicked">Blue Background</Button>
                <Button Click="Yellow_Clicked">Yellow Background</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </DockPanel>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

--MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using NotifyChangeExample.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace NotifyChangeExample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        MainViewModel _main = new MainViewModel();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //DataContext = _main;
        }

        private void Red_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _main.SetBackground(Brushes.Red);
        }

        private void Blue_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _main.SetBackground(Brushes.Blue);
        }

        private void Yellow_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _main.SetBackground(Brushes.Yellow);
        }
    }
}
```

--ObservableObject.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NotifyChangeExample
{
    public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

--PersonViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NotifyChangeExample.ViewModels
{
    public class PersonViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        private string _name;

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_name))
                    return "Unknown";
                return _name;
            }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

--BackgroundViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace NotifyChangeExample.ViewModels
{
    public class BackgroundViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        private Brush _color;

        public Brush Color
        {
            get
            {
                if (_color == null)
                    return Brushes.Orange;
                return _color;
            }
            set
            {
                _color = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Color");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

--MainViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace NotifyChangeExample.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel
    {
        public PersonViewModel Person { get; private set; }
        public BackgroundViewModel Background { get; private set; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Person = new PersonViewModel();
            Background = new BackgroundViewModel();      
        }

        public void SetBackground(Brush brushColor)
        {
            Background.Color = brushColor;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: with `<VM:MainViewModel x:Key="bc" />` you have **2** MainViewModel objects. Currently buttons always work with the one created in code-behind, even if you set "bc" as DataContext.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34617048/1136211. I'm about to close this as a duplicate, although the question *sounds* completely different.

Comment: If you really want to follow MVVM, you should move those click events out of code-behind, and convert them in to an `ICommand` implementation on the viewmodel.

Comment: I am planning on using ICommand in this project as an exercise in Mvvm.  I just want to make sure I am not missing any understandings on datacontexts before I proceed with the next implementation of this sample.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies.  The suggested link stackoverflow.com/a/34617048/1136211 had the solution I was looking for --- I can set the datacontext in the xaml and then declare _main in the code behind like this -- _main = (MainViewModel)DataContext;  now my sample project works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code behind is using the _main object so if you want to set the DataContext in the XAML, you just need to set _main using the DataContext.

So in the XAML you would have

```
<Window.DataContext>        
    <VM:MainViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

and in your code behind you would set _main by casting the DataContext to a MainViewModel

```
MainViewModel _main;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _main = (MainViewModel) DataContext;
}
```

---

Alternatively, remove the DataContext from XAML, and use this MainWindow constructor:

```
private readonly MainViewModel _main = new MainViewModel();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = _main;
}
```

Comment: I updated the answer slightly. If setting the DataContext in the XAML, you don't need to new up the MainViewModel in the code behind.

Answer (score 1):

When you are binding your ViewModel from XAML it can't work, because in your code-behind you are setting the colors to your local ViewModel "_main". But _main is  not bound to the View, bc is.

Comment: I guess my question is this -- is there a way to bind _main to the view in my current setup?  Or is code behind the only way for this setup?

Comment: Try what Marc has answered.